# API returns code not found

Tags: openfda

For a number of codes found in the National Drug Code directory the API returns code not found.
https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/ndc/index.cfm

I have reviewed the API documentation and tried building a number of queries to try and look up information about a drug given the package ndc.  all return a code:"Not_Found" error.

Here's a list of a few different api calls I have tried.

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=package_ndc:%2225021-166-48%22

https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=package_ndc:%2225021-166-48%22

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=product_ndc:%2225021-166-48%22

https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=product_ndc:%2225021-166-48%22

I have tried removing the hyphens, putting the search field in quotes, and adding a limit at the end with an &

Can anyone advise on how to get information about a drug with the API by ndc code?

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL to get the NDC record is [this](https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=packaging.package_ndc:%2225021-166-48%22). Please note that `package_ndc` is a sub-field of the top-level `packaging` element.

The correct URL to get the label is [this](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.package_ndc:%2225021-166-48%22). Please note that `package_ndc` is a sub-field of the top-level `openfda` element.

You can determine correct path to the fields you need by looking at the "[Searchable Fields](https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/ndc/searchable-fields)" documentation on the openFDA website.